# How to substitute only second occurrence of re.search() group

Tags: python, regex

I need to replace part of the string value with extra zeroes if it needs.

**T-46-5-В,Г,6-В,Г ---> T-46-005-В,Г,006-В,Г or
T-46-55-В,Г,56-В,Г ---> T-46-055-В,Г,066-В,Г**, for example.

I have Regex pattern `^\D-\d{1,2}-([\d,]+)-[а-яА-я,]+,([\d,]+)-[а-яА-я,]+$` that retrieves 2 separate groups of the string, that i must change. The problem is I can't substitute back exact same groups with changed values if there is another occurrence of my `re.search().group()` in the whole string.

```
import re

my_string = "T-46-5-В,Г,6-В,Г"
my_pattern = r"^\D-\d{1,2}-([\d,]+)-[а-яА-я,]+,([\d,]+)-[а-яА-я,]+$"

new_string_parts = ["005", "006"]
new_string = re.sub(re.search(my_pattern, my_string).group(1), new_string_parts[0], my_string)
new_string = re.sub(re.search(my_pattern, my_string).group(2), new_string_parts[1], new_string)
print(new_string)
```

I get `T-4006-005-В,Г,006-В,Г` instead of `T-46-005-В,Г,006-В,Г` because there is another *"6"* in `my_string`. How can i solve this?
Thanks for your answers!

Comment: You could capture the other parts in 3 groups and match the numbers that you want to replace. `^(\D-\d{1,2}-)[\d,]+(-[а-яА-Я,]+,)[\d,]+(-[а-яА-Я,]+)$` https://regex101.com/r/9Bqey5/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the parts you need to keep and use a single `re.sub` pass with unambiguous backreferences in the replacement part (because they are mixed with numeric string variables):

```
import re

my_string = "T-46-5-В,Г,6-В,Г"
my_pattern = r"^(\D-\d{1,2}-)[\d,]+(-[а-яёА-ЯЁ,]+,)[\d,]+(-[а-яёА-ЯЁ,]+)$"

new_string_parts = ["005", "006"]
new_string = re.sub(my_pattern, fr"\g<1>{new_string_parts[0]}\g<2>{new_string_parts[1]}\3", my_string)
print(new_string)
# => T-46-005-В,Г,006-В,Г
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/3u6Dty). Note I also added `ёЁ` to the Russian letter ranges.

The pattern - `^(\D-\d{1,2}-)[\d,]+(-[а-яёА-ЯЁ,]+,)[\d,]+(-[а-яёА-ЯЁ,]+)$` - now contains parentheses around the parts you do not need to change, and `\g<1>` refers to the string captured with `(\D-\d{1,2}-)`, `\g<2>` refers to the value captured with `(-[а-яёА-ЯЁ,]+,)` and `\3` - to `(-[а-яёА-ЯЁ,]+)`.